# How to filter DNS queries by dns.qry.name in tshark?

Tags: tshark

This will print the host names of DNS queries:

```
tshark -n -T fields -e dns.qry.name src port 53
```

How can I filter by the value of `dns.qry.name` (or get some reasonable proxy of that)? I've tried variations of `tshark -n -T fields -e dns.qry.name src port 53 and dns query name contains '"foo"'`, but they are all invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more easily done with a *display (wireshark) filter* than with a *capture (pcap) filter*.

```
tshark -n -T fields -e dns.qry.name -f 'src port 53' -Y 'dns.qry.name contains "foo"'
```

See the `pcap-filter` man page for what you can do with capture filters. It's quite limited, you'd have to dissect the protocol by hand. Here, as an approximation, assuming the query name is always 0x20 bytes within the udp packet (for DNS over UDP) and knowing that a query name shouldn't be greater than 253 bytes:

```
$ printf foo | xxd -p
666f6f
$ tshark -n -T fields -e dns.qry.name -f "src port 53 and $(awk '
    BEGIN{
      for(i=0;i<250;i++) {
        printf sep "(udp[%d]!=0&&((udp[%d:4]&0xffffff00)==0x666f6f00", i+20, i+20
        c = c "))"; sep = "||"
      }
      print c
    }')"
```